# Why does "forsake" mean abandon considering "sake" means "for the purpose of"

Tags: etymology

"Sake" means "for the purpose of," e.g. "the couple moved to the coast for the sake of her health".

Forsake means "abandon (someone or something)", for example - "he would never forsake Tara."

When considering the meaning of "sake", why does "forsake" have such a different meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Sake' can also mean 'benefit', for instance, "for goodness sake," or "Do it for his sake." The prefix for- changes the meaning to 'not benefit' (forgo, forget)